# How to use Osmosis library to obtain images from PBF

Tags: maps, osmosis, osm.pbf

I'm developing an Android application where I need to display geographical maps. I know there are alternatives, but the way I need to do it is to provide the client with the ability to receive PBF data and from the backend and there construct the images "tiles" that will make up a certain portion of the map.

To do this, I would like to use OSM PBF data and use the Osmosis library to convert this data into "tiles" that can then compose the map. However, I haven't been able to find good documentation for the Osmosis library, so I'm not even sure if this is actually achievable using it or i need to futher study PBF and make my own implementation for this use case.

Can anyone tell me if it's possible to achieve this result using the Osmosis library and perhaps give me a guideline on how to do it? Besides the images, it would be nice if I could also get the geographic coordinates of the image from its center or similar, is all of this acheaveble with Osmosis? how much control do i have over the "image" map apperence?